# How do I use /setblock and place a stone brick stair in the outer right shape?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I can't quite place a stair the direction I want it to go and I need to know the format of how to do that command. I have already attempted to do

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:stone_brick_stairs 2
                       and 
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:stone_brick_stairs 3 etc.
```

However I end up with either of these two situations:

[image: stairs not forming a corner with the wall]
[image: stairs not connecting with the nearby stairs]

but I want it to be like this:
[image: stairs connecting to the wall AND nearby stairs]

I've tried this but then it looks kinda ugly:
[image: another set of stairs to create the corner but cutting into the wall]

This is the whole room layout:
[image: room layout]

Comment: I have a question about your layout. On the corner piece (the part you want the stair next to), the stair block goes along the wall (without a door), and that is evident in picture 2. What about the corner piece next the stair placed the way you want to (last picture)? Is it positioned the same way?

Comment: no that pic is on the other side

Comment: I just posted another screenshot... does that help?

Comment: Does my answer work?

Answer (score 3):

**It seems that the problem is not with the `setblock` command, but with the stair position right behind it.**

If I'm seeing this right...

▶ = stair placed sideways to wall
▼ = stair placed pointing away from wall

When you look at the stairs, corner stairs are actually placed in a certain way. These diagrams will represent the way they are placed.  ◫ is a wall block. **Do NOT remove the wall blocks.** Only change the stairs that you have already placed.

**First picture:**

```
◫◫◫◫◫◫
◫▼▼▼▼▼
◫▶
```

**Second picture:**

```
◫◫◫◫◫◫
◫▼▼▼▼▼
◫▼
```

**This placement creates the stairs you want:**

```
◫◫◫◫◫◫
◫▶▼▼▼▼
◫▼
```

Is it clearer now? Try placing by hand first before `setblock` so you can see where I'm getting at.

Comment: It looks ugly that way and I' m trying to make a laboratory not an ugly disaster (no offence, sorry :/ )

Comment: Sorry, I think you are misunderstanding what I'm saying. Don't remove the pillar. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: Ohhh thank you for the troubles!! Have a good morning (if u live in north america...)

Comment: @Evan - remember to mark the answer as 'accepted' if it helps you. You can do this by clicking the checkmark under the vote count :)

Answer (score 0):

The corner stairs are not actually stairs rotated in that direction, but a special texture when the stair that is rotated 90 degrees from the original direction, thus to get the special rotation you need another stair next to it.